# ASP.NET MVC Using Castle Windsor IoC

Tags: inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have an app, modelled on the one from Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC that uses castle windsor's IoC to instantiate the controllers with their respective repositories, and this is working fine

e.g.

```
public class ItemController : Controller
{
    private IItemsRepository itemsRepository;
    public ItemController(IItemsRepository windsorItemsRepository)
    {
        this.itemsRepository = windsorItemsRepository;
    }
```

with

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Castle.Windsor;
using Castle.Windsor.Configuration.Interpreters;
using Castle.Core.Resource;
using System.Reflection;
using Castle.Core;

namespace WebUI
{
    public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        WindsorContainer container;

        // The constructor:
        // 1. Sets up a new IoC container
        // 2. Registers all components specified in web.config
        // 3. Registers all controller types as components
        public WindsorControllerFactory()
        {
            // Instantiate a container, taking configuration from web.config
            container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter(new ConfigResource("castle")));

            // Also register all the controller types as transient
            var controllerTypes = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                                  where typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                                  select t;
            foreach (Type t in controllerTypes)
                container.AddComponentWithLifestyle(t.FullName, t, LifestyleType.Transient);
        }

        // Constructs the controller instance needed to service each request
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(Type controllerType)
        {
            return (IController)container.Resolve(controllerType);
        }
    }
}
```

controlling the controller creation.

I sometimes need to create other repository instances within controllers, to pick up data from other places, can I do this using the CW IoC, if so then how?

I have been playing around with the creation of new controller classes, as they should auto-register with my existing code (if I can get this working, I can register them properly later) but when I try to instantiate them there is an obvious objection as I can't supply a repos class for the constructor (I was pretty sure that was the wrong way to go about it anyway).

Any help (especially examples) would be much appreciated.
Cheers
MH

Comment: What was your conclusion in the end. I have the same design issue.

Comment: Shortly after looking at this I found a memory leak in the application, this was coming from somewhere in the Castle Windsor code (whether it was me using it incorrectly, or not, I don't know, but I was using it at a simple level so I'm not 100% sure it _was_ me) so I didn't get around to checking these solutions out - sorry. If you try the below solution and it works, please let me know and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it doesn`t work anymore wih last version of windor castle, in fact, microkernel assembly was melting inside castle.core

Comment: Your croaker Nell was melting inside the castle? Sounds like a Trojan horse, I mean frog.

Answer (score 5):

Just declare your required dependencies in your controller constructor, i.e.:

```
public class MyController: Controller {
  private readonly IItemsRepository itemsRepo;
  private readonly IPersonRepository personRepo;
  public MyController(IItemsRepository i, IPersonRepository p) {
    itemsRepo = i;
    personRepo = p;
  }
}
```

Windsor will resolve the dependencies automatically when it instantiates the controller.

There are lots of projects on google code that you can use for guidance, for instance [WineCellarManager](http://code.google.com/p/winecellarmanager).

BTW: you don't need to code your own WindsorControllerFactory, you can get that (and a lot more) from [MVCContrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib)

Comment: That's not always practical, for example in the object validation rules I need to check any part numbers added against the main DB - it is better to do this in the object as it keeps the business logic out of the controllers, but the object doesn't have a repos (nor do I really want to create one, unless I need to check the data)

Comment: Validation has nothing to do with this... please create another question for that

Comment: It does, because in my validation rules I need access to the database repos.

Comment: It's not related to wiring controllers and services with Windsor. It's more a design question than a how-to question. Please create another question...